# How do I hide div id's with onclick menu without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Heres the menu:**

```
<a href="" onclick="loadPage('page1')">Home</a>
<a href="" onclick="loadPage('page2')">About us</a>
<a href="" onclick="loadPage('page3')">Services</a>
<a href="" onclick="loadPage('page4')">Partners</a>
<a href="" onclick="loadPage('page5')">Contact us</a>
```

**Heres the script so far:**

```
<script>    
    var var1="";
    function loadPage(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
      elem.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

**Here's the div:**

```
<div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
    <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
    <p1 id="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
</div>
```

Basically i want some JavaScript that if home is clicked then hide page 2, 3, 4 and 5. And so on. Don't post jquery tried that last time it simply didn't work.

Comment: Where is `elem` defined?

Comment: If jQuery didnt work the last time, then there's something wrong with that code.

Comment: please don't tag jquery if you don't want jquery -- also, html elements should not have multiple with the same id -- you'll need your function to hide all page elements that are not the element being selected.  jquery will absolutely work for this, 'simply didn't work' is not accurate

Comment: But it didn't though, i followed everything right as instructed it simply didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/28/

Couple problems.

First off, you should NOT use the same `ID` for multiple elements, you `CLASS` instead. In your case the parent div already is using the right `ID` when you display that `ID` to `none` all its children elements are gone too.

Change this: `onclick="loadPage('page1')"`

To this: `onclick="loadPage('page_1')"` notice this matches your `<div id="page_1">`

And this is not being used at all `elem.style.display = "none";`, what is `elem` (you never defined it) I changed it to this `document.getElementById(var1).style.display = "none";` because `var1` is being declared and set to the right `id`

Last but not least, I added a hashtag to your link href so the page does not reload:

`<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('page_1')">Home</a>`

**HTML**

```
<div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
  <h1 class="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
  <p1 class="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security
    <br> for the
    <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
</div>
```

**Javascript, Updated since the comments specify the issue**

```
  //this hides all div's except fot the first one
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (i === 1)
      document.getElementById('page_' + i).style.display = "block"
    else
      document.getElementById('page_' + i).style.display = "none"
  }

  //hides all div's and shows only div that was clicked
  function loadPage(varcontent) {
    var var1 = "";
    var1 = varcontent;
    var num = var1.slice(-1);

    document.getElementById(var1).style.display = "block";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i == num)
        document.getElementById('page_' + i).style.display = "block"
      else
        document.getElementById('page_' + i).style.display = "none"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great!! though I want Page1 to stay visible if you click home and disappear if click about etc. Best result I've had all day!

Comment: @TimMarshall ok, give me a minute to revise

Comment: @TimMarshall here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/27/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mtf7La5p/1/)**

```js
function loadPage(page){
  for(var i=1; i<= 4; i++){
    if(('page_'+i) == page)
      document.getElementById('page_'+i).style.display = "block"
    else
      document.getElementById('page_'+i).style.display = "none"
   }
}
   
loadPage('page_1')
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('page_1')">Home</a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('page_2')">About us</a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('page_3')">Services</a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('page_4')">Partners</a>

<div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
  <h1 >Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
  <p1 >An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
</div>
<div id="page_2" class=welcome_bye_holder>
  <h1 >aboutus:</h1>
  <p1 >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown prin.</p1>
</div>
<div id="page_3" class=welcome_bye_holder>
  <h1 >services</h1>
  <p1 >pesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown prin</p1>
</div>
<div id="page_4" class=welcome_bye_holder>
  <h1 >partners:</h1>
  <p1 >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown prin</p1>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I'm getting the same result as last time, the code snippet works here but not on my website?